# shared lib file not found when import torch

Tags: shared-libraries

I installed torch on my machine to run the latest onnxruntime tests and got this error.

> ImportError: /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcublas.so.10: version
> `libcublas.so.10' not found (required by
> /home/users/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so)

But this file does exist and I've made sure with command

```
ll /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcublas.so.10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Dec 20 11:46 /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcublas.so.10 -> /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcublas.so.10.0
```

I've checked `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and found that `/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/` is already in it. I've tried to put it to the front of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and still not working.

I've also tried to use ldd to see the lib file connection and did not get much info.

```
ldd /home/users/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so
/home/users/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcublas.so.10: version `libcublas.so.10' not found (required by /home/users/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffffb33e000)
        libc10_cuda.so => /home/users/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10_cuda.so (0x00007fedb38ae000)
        libcudart-80664282.so.10.2 => /home/users/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libcudart-80664282.so.10.2 (0x00007fedb362d000)
        libnvToolsExt-3965bdd0.so.1 => /home/users/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libnvToolsExt-3965bdd0.so.1 (0x00007fedb3423000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fedb3207000)
        libc10.so => /home/users/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so (0x00007fedb2f77000)
        libtorch_cpu.so => /home/users/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.so (0x00007fed9a500000)
        libm.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fed9a1fe000)
        libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fed99ffa000)
        libcublas.so.10 => /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcublas.so.10 (0x00007fed95a64000)
        librt.so.1 => /usr/lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fed9585c000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/gcc-5.4.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fed954e1000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/gcc-5.4.0/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fed952ca000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fed94efc000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fede3d1e000)
        libgomp-a34b3233.so.1 => /home/users/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libgomp-a34b3233.so.1 (0x00007fed94cd2000)
```

Comment: /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcublas.so.10 and /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcublas.so.10.0 are both soft link to /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcublas.so.10.0.130

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because I set the LD_LIBRARY and caused this issue.

I searched the local files and found there are multiple places that have this file:

```
...
/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcublas.so.10
/home/users/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libcublas.so.10
```

So it is because I have `/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcublas.so.10` this softlink in my system, it used this instead of its own lib file. After I removed this softlink, it worked.